# How do I edit a commit that is a common ancestor of multiple branches?

Tags: git, git-rebase

```
branch A
|
| branch B
| |
|/
|
commit X
|
|
...
```

How do I edit commit X to become X' such that both A and B have X' in their history? (All commits and branches are local.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to rewrite branches history (with all its implications):

```
git checkout x
# do changes
git add .
git commit --amend
# now we have X'... let's create a temp branch here
git branch temp
git rebase --onto temp x A # rebase branch A onto temp
git rebase --onto temp x B # rebase branch B onto temp
```

Now, you could delete temp

```
git branch -d temp
```