# git rebase if the nodes have multiple ancestors

Tags: git, rebase

Is there a way to squash old commits that are ancestors to multiple branches, *while preserving the structure of all branches*? E.g. in the following example I want

commit Y

simply gone:

```
  branch A
  |
  | branch B
  | |
  |/
  |
  commit Z
  commit Y
  commit X
  |
  |
```

It is fine if the hashes of the nodes change, and they will, however the *tree needs to stay the same*, i.e. I do not want a single new branch with the nodes deleted, I already know how to do that, but rather the nodes need to be deleted in all the branches and the tree structure must be preserved.

If somebody knows how to do this and is willing to share, I would really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Any changing of the git commit history _will only ever add new commits_. Rebasing? Adds new commits. Squashing? Adds new commits.

Comment: So you agree that there is no way?I find it very odd. If it were a single branch, then it would be a simple rebase. However, if I did that a new branch would stand by itself. All I am trying to achieve is get rid of some commits that were done in order not to lose any work. They might be as descriptive as .... or contain misspellings etc. They are not needed, and yet there seems to be no way to get rid of them. This question might be maybe relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59003005/how-do-i-edit-a-commit-that-is-a-common-ancestor-of-multiple-branches but honestly idk. BTW Tx.

Comment: May you clarify your understanding of a few things? 1. What is a branch (or the structure of a branch)? 2. What are you worried about losing by rebasing/squashing?

Comment: Also, may you format the question a bit? It's almost impossible to read the commit log properly

Comment: I just did, I think. You have two branches A and B. They have to remain as they are except that the commit Y needs to be squashed, or deleted otherwise removed. It does not matter if all nodes in the tree are new, and they will need to be recreated  for sure, but the tree needs to stay as it is for all practical purposes -- new hashes for the commits don't really matter.

Answer (score 1):

The interactive rebase code, in modern Git (since 2.18, although there have been some fixes since then), has almost enough *internal machinery* to do this under `git rebase --rebase-merges`.  Unfortunately the external interface requires that the branches be merged and does not update multiple *branch names* in the process.  Making the external interface smart enough to do this is ... difficult.

The end result is that you must run multiple separate `git rebase` commands, one for each branch.  You must plan ahead for this so that you know which commits each rebase will copy, and use `git rebase --onto` for some of the rebase operations.

In your own example, we have, as a starting setup:

```
                A1--A2--A3   <-- branchA
               /
...--W--X--Y--Z
               \
                B1--B2--B3   <-- branchB
```

for instance.  Here the newest commits are towards the right, so that commit `A1` has `Z` as its parent and `B1` has `Z` as its parent; `A3` and `B3` are the latest commits that are *only on one branch*.

Since rebase works by copying, we will:

- pick one of the two branches to rebase, where we'll squash X and Y together, then
- pick the other branch to fix up afterwards.

If we pick `branchA` first, we will run:

```
git checkout branchA
git rebase -i HEAD~7
```

This allows us to `pick` commit `X`, change the `pick` for commit `Y` to a `squash`, and leave the remaining `pick` operations alone.  The copying-and-squashing now occurs, leaving us with:

```
         XY--Z'-A1'-A2'-A3'  <-- branchA
        /
       /        A1--A2--A3   [branchA@{1}]
      /        /
...--W--X--Y--Z
               \
                B1--B2--B3   <-- branchB
```

To copy the three `B` commits atop the `Z'` commit, we must now:

```
git checkout branchB
git rebase --onto branchA~3 branchA@{1}
```

or similar.  This particular second command makes use of the *reflog* for `branchA`, via the `branch@{1}` spelling.  Since reflogs are actually optional, we must be sure that they are enabled before we run the *first* rebase.

(The count, `3`, in `branchA~3`, also depends on the number of commits between the tip of `branchA` and our target `Z'`, whose hash ID is not available until the first rebase completes.)

Comment: @HEY does this answer your question?

Comment: @evolutionxbox: this is just the long form of what HEY put up as an answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is done branch by branch using

```
git rebase --onto ...
```

Comment: May you explain why?