# Automatically rebase all branches containing a changed commit

Tags: git

When I have a git history in which a commit belongs to multiple branches and would like to change the commit on all branches keeping the branch structure as it is.

Let's say the commit is on master, and later some branches were created, and maybe even the branches have new branches. All branches have the commit in their history. When I now change the commit in the master branch, the other branches start at the commit before the changed commit and contain duplicates of the following commits as they start at the original parent commit and not the changed one. So I need to remove the original commit in each of the branches and rebase ech of the branches onto the correct parent commit manually.

Is there a way to **automatically** ensure all branches are rebased on the changed commit without manually rebasing them one-by-one?

The question is NOT answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59003149) as it only shows a way how to do it manually.

Comment: @Joe No. This (close to) my current workflow, but I am looking for an answer how to automate it. git knows what branches the commit is on, so it should be possible to automatically rebase all branches onto the new commit without doing it one-by-one.

Comment: I agree that this question is not the duplicate. I also suggest to add the keyword `automatically` to the question title.

Comment: There is no facility that does it automatically for you. You could merge all affected branches into a throw-away branch, then `git rebase -i -r` that branch. That gets you the required rebased branch history, but still does not update the branch pointers.

Comment: One solution that works in the general sense, but may be overkill if a looped rebase would work well: 1.) Make the new commit. 2.) `git replace` the old and new commit. 3.) Lock it in with `git-filter-repo` or `git-filter-branch`.